# Call a function before jetty stop

Tags: java, windows-services, jetty

In the project I am working on, we need to "save" the work before jetty stopped, on linux this is just easy, because we can call another process, on windows, this is not easy, because we are registering in into Windows service, which means we can either modify the start.jar file to make something before the "stop" function being called, or, well here I need help:

I want, that jetty executes some process before it trigger the stop() function, or even before calling the start.Main class, is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [shutdown hooks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

> When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently. **When all the hooks have finished it will then run all uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled. Finally, the virtual machine will halt.**

That is, a shutdown hook keeps the JVM running until the hook has terminated (returned from the *run()*-method.

You will have to extend Jetty code with this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually what I need is: I want that some "shutdown-hook" triggered before JETTY stopped, this way I can save my work over JETTY, and this is really important. I know the solution of Shutdown-hook, and implemented it already in some other parts...

Comment: You can imagine it as: I need something similar to some function, that runs before jetty Main.stop being executed, so that I have JETTY running... I have read about some LifeCycle, but can't get any idea how to get into it...